# Two accesses to a web app embedded in an IFrame on a different website are two different sessions to the app?

Tags: spring-mvc, iframe

I am doing a Spring MVC web app. It runs on Tomcat. It is embedded through iFrame in a page of another totally unrelated website. If two users access this page and my web app is displayed to them.

Question: to my web app, the two accesses are technically two different sessions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the two accesses are different sessions. In loading the page shown inside the iFrame, I added the following:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
System.out.println(session.getId());
```

The system displays different IDs for the two accesses. If someone seems anything wrong in what I did, please feel free to chime in.

Cheers.